# Postgresql Function execute format dynamic DDL value error

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dbeaver

So, i need to make a function that can generate schema & table that schema name and table name depend on parameter send called **_schema_name** for schema name & **_tp_table_name** for table name.

My pgsql function code right now :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.addschema(_schema_name character varying, _tp_table_name character varying )
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

begin 
    
    execute format('CREATE schema %I',_schema_name);

    execute format('CREATE TABLE %I.%I( id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
                        raw_id uuid NULL)', _schema_name, _tp_table_name);

RETURN _schema_name;
END;

$function$
;
```

so i run the function with this :

```
select addschema('newschema','new_tbl');
```

i've got an error like this :

```
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: unrecognized format() type specifier "I"
  Hint: For a single "%" use "%%".
  Where: PL/pgSQL function addschema(character varying,character varying) line 11 at EXECUTE
```

anyone have any hints? thank you..

Comment: Your function is just fine. Which client are you using?

Comment: i use dbeaver 7.23

Comment: Can you execute it using `psql` or `pgadmin`? I just tested your function here and it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to be somewhere in the client side. Your function looks just fine. I've tested it (slightly formatted) in `psql`, `pgAdmin4` and `DBeaver 21.2.0.202108310918`.. all worked just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.addschema(_schema_name text, _tp_table_name text )
 RETURNS text 
AS $$
BEGIN 
 EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA %I;',_schema_name);
 EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I.%I( id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
                       raw_id uuid NULL)', _schema_name, _tp_table_name);
 RETURN _schema_name;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

DBeaver screenshot:

[image]

Alternatively, you can take look at the database log files to see how the query is actually being sent to the database. Also, in case you're using an older PostgreSQL version, [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) is supported only after PostgreSQL 9.6+

Comment: ahh.. that's right, apparently it's only a problem in the postgres version, this happens only in local postgre but not in my project server database. thank you! solved now